# c - difficulties with bit operations

Tags: c, gdb, bitwise-operators

I'm debugging a program with GDB.

```
unsigned int example = ~0;
```

gives me:

```
(gdb) x/4bt example
0xffd99788:     10101000        10010111        11011001        11111111
```

why is this not all 1's? i defined it as ~0... then the next line of code is:

```
example>>=(31);
```

and GDB gives me this when I try to examine the memory at bits:

```
(gdb) x/4bt example
0xffffffff:     Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff
```

what is going on???

Comment: Are you sure that line is being run?  It may not be initialized if you don't "run" your program after you load it and the variable is global.  Put a breakpoint in main and then look around.

Comment: i know it's being run. i set a bpoint to get to a line before i start printing things

Comment: @luqui: It can't be global if the "next line" is `example>>=(31);`.

Comment: Raul's answer indicates the problem but I think you are also trying to print out the value one line too early each time. gdb prints out the line that will be executed _next_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to take the address of example in the gdb statement:

```
(gdb) x/4bt &example
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that the `x` command examines memory, so `example` would be interpreted as pointer. Try

```
x/4bt &example
```

or simply

```
print /x example
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the gdb command format but looking at the last statement it seems like you want to see what is at the address stored in `example` instead of printing `example` ... it seems that `example` is `all 1s` (`0xffffffff`) and you are trying to look at that location in memory when you get the error.